# How to enable mod_rewrtie on ubuntu on bitnami machine on Amazon?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, lamp, bitnami

I have created a lamp bitnami server on Amazon. I was wondering how to enable mod_rewrite on it? 
This is the server that I have http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack

I have tried installing "sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common"

then running "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and then editing "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default" and making "AllowOverride all", then restarted the server.

But nothing works...

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I normally just do "sudo a2enmod rewrite". Can you explain what you mean by "nothing works?" i.e. what are the error messages? Perhaps ask this question on Serverfault.com, might get help there quicker.

Comment: by nothing works, I mean the .htaccess file is not getting in effect. It dosent redirect the url as expected.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to install anything, it is already enabled but you can check the Apache configuration file:

/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

```
...
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```